# XPath translate to CSS

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors

i need ur help i want to translate from XPath to css i have this code and this xpath: 
`/descendant::p/parent::*/child::p[position()=1]` ...  Selected will be (B D F H )

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<book>
     <title>A</title>
     <p>B</p>
     <p>C</p>
<chapter>
    <p>D</p>
    <p>E</p>
    <section>
        <p>F</p>
        <section>
            <title>G</title>
            <p>H</p>
        </section>
        <p>I</p>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

HOW i can translate this to CSS?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about what you're exactly looking for, but using [`p:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) selects the first paragraph elements inside their parent:

```css
p:first-of-type {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

Selected elements: `B D F H`: **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ganonidu/1/edit)**.

Comment: And if the css selector starts with " book:root " how should i contenuie

Comment: @RaedKHakim I'm not sure what does `:root` mean in XPath, but generally for each `book` you can use `book p:first-of-type`.

Comment: @RaedKHakim Don't mention it :)

Comment: Hashem i have another Question maybe u can help me

Comment: I have this XPath and i dont understand it very well so how would be the xml file structre like

/child::p/child::c [preceding-sibling::* = following-sibling::* and preceding-sibling::* != following-sibling::*]

please help me i have tomorrow an exam :D

Comment: @RaedKHakim lol, nor do I understand it. Better to ask that as a new question. I'll try my best to figure it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
p:first-of-type {
    /** Your style here **/
    color: red;
}
```

Supports all major browsers and IE9+

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp)

Comment: No, IE8 does not support `:first-of-type`. You probably meant IE9+.